# How to prevent Drawer Navigator refresh in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a `DrawerNavigator` with a list of screens. The problem is that if I go to another screen and come back, the first screen re-initializes completely. How to prevent this re-initialization so that whatever the state of the first screen was, is preserved on coming back?